# How to fit html page on a4 size page using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I have been working for days to fix this but I couldn't maybe because of lack of knowledge of html2canva or it is doesn't want to be fixed. What only I want is to fit my pdf on a single page with a4 size but it always rendered on two pages. Don't know where I am going wrong. please suggest something.

This is my code:

```js
document.querySelector('#temp').contentEditable = true;

function createpdf() {
  let body = document.body
  let html = document.documentElement
  let height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight)
  let element = document.querySelector('#temp')
  let heightCM = height / 35.35
  html2pdf(element, {
    margin: 1,
    filename: 'MyResume.pdf',
    image: {
      type: 'jpeg',
      quality: 4
    },
    html2canvas: {
      dpi: 400,
      letterRendering: true,
      scale: 3
    },
    jsPDF: {
      orientation: 'portrait',
      unit: 'cm',
      //   format: [heightCM, 50]
      format: 'a4'

    }
  }).save()
}
```

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 1cm;
}

/* p{
  font-size: 10px;
}
b{
  font-size: 10px;
}
li{
  font-size: 10px;
} */

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: -4px;
}

.spacing {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.paddingtop {
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.paddingbottom {
  padding-bottom: -14px;
}

.right1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  padding-top: -53px;
}

.right2 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  padding-top: -60px;
}

.right3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  padding-top: -52px;
}

.border1 {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 596px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.border2 {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 596px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.border3 {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 596px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.blankline {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

[contenteditable]:focus {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}


/* #pdf {
  width:650px;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  left:29%;
  font-size:16px;
} */

#page {
  /* width: 794px; */
  /* height: 29.7cm; */
  width: 21cm;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% auto 1% auto;
  padding: 0.2cm 1.3cm 1cm 1.3cm;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.3/html2pdf.bundle.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/wscbundle/wscbundle.js"></script>

<section id="page">
  <div id="temp">
    <h1>Nitin</h1>
    <p class="paddingbottom">
      <b>INFO</b>
    </p>
    <p class="paddingtop">
      <b>Address: </b> 44 Shirley Ave, West Chicago, IL 60185
    </p>
    <p class="spacing">
      <b>Phone:</b> 563-458-6942
    </p>
    <p class="blankline">
      <b>Email:</b> jmiller@gmail.com
    </p>
    <p class="paddingbottom">
      <b>PROFESSIONAL SUMMARY</b>
    </p>
    <p class="paddingtop blankline">
      A highly resourceful, flexible, innovative and enthusiastic project manager. Processing considerable experience of managing projects from beginning to end, defining the project plan, timeline, scope and executing the analysis before providing detailed
      recommendations. Having an impressive track record of delivering major operational improvement and of orchestrating people, schedules and resources for optimum productivity, efficiency and quality. Keen to find a challenging position with an ambitious
      company where I will able to continue to increase my project management skills.
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Oct. 2015 - Apr. 2016</b>
      <br>
      <b>B.Tech (CSE)</b>
    </p>
    <p class="right1">
      Kurukshetra University
      <br> Seth Jai Prakash Mukand Lal Institute of Engineering and Technology, Raduar, District Yamunanagar
      <br> 79.48%
    </p>
    <p class="">
      <b>May 2017 - Jun. 2018</b>
      <br>
      <b>Senior Secondary Certificate</b>
    </p>
    <p class="right2">
      CBSE
      <br> S.D. Public School, Jagadhri
      <br> 92%
    </p>
    <p class="">
      <b>May 2017 - Jun. 2018</b>
      <br>
      <b>Matriculation</b>
    </p>
    <p class="right3">
      ICSE
      <br> St. Thomas School, Jagadhri
      <br> 84.6%
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>TECHNICAL SKILLS</b>
      <ul>
        <li>Beginner of - </li>
        <li>Proficient in - </li>
        <li class="blankline">Sufficient knowledge of - </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>PROJECTS</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="blankline">
          <b>JARVIS - PERSONAL ASSISTANT - </b>
          <br>
          <p>(This project assists the end-user with day to day activities like searching queries in Google, finding locations, sending emails, playing songs, searching instagram profiles, opening webcam and many more.)</p>
        </li>
        <li class="blankline">
          <b>TRAVEL MANIA - </b>
          <br>
          <p>(It is a travelling website that enables users to plan their travel without any hassle. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)</p>
        </li>
        <li class="blankline">
          <b>RESPRO - </b>
          <br>
          <p> (It is a website that provides a simple and efficient way of creating resume and cover letter for individuals. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>TRAININGS</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="blankline">
          <p>Attended 40 days training on “C++” at “WEBCOM Technologies, Yamunanagar” (Jun. 2019 to Jul. 2019).</p>
        </li>
        <li class="blankline">
          <p>Attended 21.5 hours training on "Python" from "Udemy" (Jul. 2020 to Aug. 2020).</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>SOFT SKILLS</b>
      <ul>
        <li>Teamwork</li>
        <li>Leadership</li>
        <li>Communication skills</li>
        <li>Time management</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p class="border blankline">
      <b>ACHIEVEMENTS</b>
      <ul>
        <li>Won third position in FashP competition (2019).</li>
        <li>Won first position in Flower Arrangement competition (2012).</li>
        <li class="blankline">Won second position in Drawing competition (2012).</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>

</section>

<button id="Download" onclick="createpdf();">Download</button>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] -  The spellchecker does not work in a stack snippet, but is also not part of your problem

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem for export HTML to PDF. I create canvas per div.
perhaps this is will help you all.

```
private canvas: any = {
    monthYearCanvas: null,
    monthYearHeight: 0,
    periodCanvas: null,
    periodHeight: 0,
    assetCanvas: null,
    assetHeight: 0,
    badActorCanvas: null,
    badActorHeight: 0,
    eventCanvas: null,
    eventHeight: 0,
    tenLowOffCanvas: null,
    tenLowOffHeight: 0,
};

public triggerPrintReport(): void {
            if (
                this.isLoadingMonthYear ||
                this.isLoadingOnPeriod ||
                this.isLoadingOnAsset ||
                this.isLoadingOnBadActor ||
                this.isLoadingOnEvent ||
                this.isLoadingTenLowOff
            ) {
                alert('Wait for load data');
                return;
            }
    
            this.messageReport = true;
    
            const monthYearHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-monthYear');
            const periodHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-period');
            const assetHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-asset');
            const badActorHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-badActor');
            const eventHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-event');
            const tenLowOffHTML = document.getElementById('htmlData-tenLowOff');
    
            this.createCanvasURL(monthYearHTML, 'monthYear');
            this.createCanvasURL(periodHTML, 'period');
            this.createCanvasURL(assetHTML, 'asset');
            this.createCanvasURL(badActorHTML, 'badActor');
            this.createCanvasURL(eventHTML, 'event');
            this.createCanvasURL(tenLowOffHTML, 'tenLowOff');
        }
    
        private createCanvasURL(element: any, type: string): void {
            html2canvas(element).then(canvas => {
                const width = 208;
    
                if (type === 'monthYear') {
                    this.canvas.monthYearHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.monthYearCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                } else if (type === 'period') {
                    this.canvas.periodHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.periodCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                } else if (type === 'asset') {
                    this.canvas.assetHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.assetCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                } else if (type === 'badActor') {
                    this.canvas.badActorHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.badActorCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                } else if (type === 'event') {
                    this.canvas.eventHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.eventCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                } else if (type === 'tenLowOff') {
                    this.canvas.tenLowOffHeight = canvas.height * width / canvas.width;
                    this.canvas.tenLowOffCanvas = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                }
    
                this.exportPDF();
            });
        }
    
        private exportPDF(): void {
            const PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    
            if (
                this.canvas.monthYearCanvas &&
                this.canvas.periodCanvas &&
                this.canvas.assetCanvas &&
                this.canvas.badActorCanvas &&
                this.canvas.badActorCanvas &&
                this.canvas.tenLowOffCanvas
            ) {
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.monthYearCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 10, 208, this.canvas.monthYearHeight);
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.periodCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 125, 208, this.canvas.periodHeight);
                PDF.addPage();
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.assetCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 10, 208, this.canvas.assetHeight);
                PDF.addPage();
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.badActorCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 10, 208, this.canvas.badActorHeight);
                PDF.addPage();
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.eventCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 10, 208, this.canvas.eventHeight);
                PDF.addPage('l');
                PDF.addImage(this.canvas.tenLowOffCanvas, 'PNG', 1, 10, 208, this.canvas.tenLowOffHeight);
    
                this.messageReport = false;
    
                PDF.save('angular-demo.pdf');
            }
        }
```